Why my lightning node does RBF onchain of a tx that does not exists? (after a forced close channel with an expired HTLC)
I am using lightning core and I had a force close channel with an active HTLC, funds were sent from this address bc1qca5lwlfv8qzkchcfqdryfl89szuk2n0c3x2p7vt4gst04keygkns4x68hh to myself (bc1qf7nh8pwt30nxueqekrhapa3wyz98zxu58rfl8l and have been spent) and after the expired HTLC (3 days later) funds were sent to the same address of force close (bc1qca5lwlfv8qzkchcfqdryfl89szuk2n0c3x2p7vt4gst04keygkns4x68hh).
Since then funds are stuck and I see in logs that is doing a RBF onchain of txid that I can not find and keeps increasing the fee (just showing two examples on logs fees going from 2728 to 14841):
Apr 10 15:59:39 nixos lightningd[1311]: INFO    021cb32426ed1a6be9533801e7c56a70ffc1c360a3a31819c3ae0a72e141d78000-chan#6: RBF onchain txid 7114510a6756715ddbed679f3c3f5787033780a800a3ef402033ee09d82630e0 (fee 2707sat) with txid ea512e00228263f53ae143416324a04b28e9381217400191ea7a031e343441c0 (fee 2728sat)
Apr 10 18:35:54 nixos lightningd[1311]: INFO    021cb32426ed1a6be9533801e7c56a70ffc1c360a3a31819c3ae0a72e141d78000-chan#6: RBF onchain txid 8d83a77b59a36f893d693e467f6e64434bf205337176113a9b569c27c0f12c78 (fee 14840sat) with txid 51eb15bc8541358912d23493b16ad9d38cac48f9a41f72ba2c05c83d6da29152 (fee 14841sat)
I would appreciate if someone can explain me why my node is doing this.
Thank you

Solved, I was able to find the raw tx in debug log, the transaction was never broadcasted but only the RBF so it did not exists. Manually broadcasting the raw tx fixed it.
